# op amp single supply with nonlinear gain below 1 and start offset

Tags: single-supply-op-amp

Is it possible to create a circuit with an op amp (single supply) that have a nonlinear gain (below 1) slope and a start offset?

See image
Green = input
Red = output

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want an overall non-linear response then you add non-linear components to the circuit. You need to supply more details if you expect a more detailed answer. In particular, how precisely do you want to control the point where the gain changes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to be able to adjust the gain breakpoint by 0.1V. The breakpoint should be at 1.5V and the input is between 0-5V DC. The output will end at 4V when input is at its maximum (5V).

Comment: What do you mean by "able to adjust the gain breakpoint"? Do you mean by redesigning the circuit and selecting different components or by twiddling a knob?

Comment: Redesigning when doing simulations...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work for  you. You can adjust the breakpoint by adjusting R2/R3 ratio (currently set at 1.5V). That will also affect the voltage at the endpoint so you'll need to change the R1/R4 ratio if you want to preserve the 4.0V out for 5.0V in.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCuqyd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A precision clamp circuit will do what you want. Consider this: -

[image]

U1 and U2 act as clamps. They clamp the signal at a positive level of V1 and a negative level of V2 (as shown in the little picture under the "clamped output").

If R1 becomes a pot then you basically have a new signal that is somewhere between fully clamped and not clamped at all. If the input doesn't go negative then you don't need the U2/V2 circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You start with a non-inverting differential amplifier with 0V reference then increase the gain when Vout =Vth of transfer function and then increase the gain to linearize the input.  Since the non-inverting gain is always 1+ Rf/Rin,  you have two choices; { if Vout > x , increase Rf or if Vin >y decrease Rin.

For Rin, Depending on the voltage error tolerance of linearity you have options to use a precision switched resistance or a std  Zener or better, a precision Zener IC with a series R,  all in parallel with the fixed Rin to increase the gain.

When the threshold of the Zener is relatively low resistance , Zzt compared to the fixed Rin, the knee is as sharp as you need it to match the input response.